# how to update a face recongition ( e.g facenet)

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, opencv

I'm searching for a face recognition that detects new faces not just faces getting from the datasets,
for example, facenet is a project that can detect and recognize a face from labels.
I would like to know how can I create a face recognition that can update faces, that means to detect new faces.
I have an idea that it this can be using SQL database that includes a faces table (face_id,face_name,face_image) but I don't know how can I fasten the database with the face recognition system.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25062/how-can-we-scale-up-the-number-of-classes-for-deep-learning-after-training-a-mod/25064#25064 - I think this is a duplicate